# How to make tabs on a tabbedpage?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning XAML/Xamarin Forms, and have been making some initial apps. However, now I am trying to replicate a design.

Quite a lot of apps have a menu such as this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

While also having tabs in the bottom of the page (iOS at least).

How is this achieved? If I make a `TabbedPage`, this adds tabs in the bottom, but adding this kind of extra "menu" - how is this done? What technique is used?

Comment: It can be just StackLayout with buttons or fragments for Andrtoid and Toolbar for iOS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems is a segmented control, already exist a NuGet package created by alex rainman, You can take a look on this. maybe this will help you.

https://github.com/alexrainman/SegmentedControl